# Copper vs Aluminium cooling (no airflow)

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, cooling

I've ordered a WD gen4 SSD (500GB), it doesn't come with heatsink and there are complaints of heating issues.

I opened up my laptop and it seems there's no airflow near the SSD slots. I measured approximately 11mm gap between the motherboard and the frame.

In online stores, I found a thin copper plate with 1mm thickness (and a passive cooler with 12mm thickness which probably won't fit) and an aluminium one with 7mm-9mm (6.6mm + top which gets pushed in 2.4mm.)

Which one will be better for my scenario?

Also let me know if I'm wrong and the gen4 SSDs don't heat up unless they have issues.

Comment: WD [specify](https://documents.westerndigital.com/content/dam/doc-library/en_us/assets/public/western-digital/product/internal-drives/wd-black-ssd/data-sheet-wd-black-sn850-nvme-ssd.pdf) (assuming it's an SN850) that the operating temperature range is 0–70 °C, so it could be that although there is no obvious air flow around it in your laptop's chassis, what there is is enough. You might want to try it first to see if there is a need for a heatsink.

Answer (score 2):

Passive heatsinks are all about providing a mass capable of absorbing heat as well as giving a larger surface area to dissipate it.

The problem with the m.2 SSD is likely that heat is focused around the controller chip and the flash memory. If there is only one flash chip (cheaper SSD) then it means all the heat is focused in small zones. Small focused heat zones are bad.

Any heatsink is going to absorb and more evenly distribute the heat across the surface area of the device, which will help keep individual parts cool by distributing heat across the full surface of the heatsink. The amount of heat generated will be the same, but as it can be distributed it will reduce the overall heat focused at any given area.

A heatsink also provides a mass that can effectively "buffer" heat under heavy loads. A small plastic chip will get hot quickly under load and will struggle to shed heat (and in your case will throttle performance) but once the load goes away it will have to slowly shed heat. The mass of the heatsink will mean that the heat has somewhere to go but it will "flow around" the metal of the heatsink resulting in a lower peak temperatures and probably slightly lower average temperatures for the hot spots. Finding a [random graph from the internet](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2352484721002742) to demonstrate I would expect to see something like this, where the blue line would be the controller without a heatsink and the green line would be with a heatsink. There would be much reduced peaks and a generally smoother graph over time.

[image]

You can think of this as a large blob of metal having a larger "thermal capacity" than a smaller blob of metal.

The fact that the heatsink has a larger surface area than the SSD chips themselves will mean that what little airflow there is around it will allow it to more efficiently transfer heat to the air resulting in slightly lower temperatures overall.

For low heat output devices that are capable of operating normally without a heatsink using anything to absorb and distribute heat will be better than not using it at all.

While copper had better thermal conductivity than aluminium, for the amount of heat that an SSD would produce is unlikely to make a significant difference. That there is no active cooling going on would mean that actual mass of the heatsink is going to make more difference as the same heat output occupying a larger mass would be a lower average temperature. In order of preference:

1. largest heatsink, the 12mm one, if it fits would be best due to the higher mass.
2. the 6-7mm heatsink would provide some mass for heat to be taken away from components and more evenly distribute heat
3. the thin 1-2mm copper heatsink would have lower thermal capacity, but would spread heat more evenly across the surface area available
4. no heatsink at all will be the worst.

Answer (score 0):

Copper has higher heat conductivity per volume.  Aluminum has higher conductivity per weight and cost.  Heat pipes beat both of them.  Thermal compound between the device and the heat spreader tries to eliminate any insulative air gap between them.

Copper also has a higher specific heat than aluminum, meaning it can absorb more heat for the same volume.

But none of that helps long term if you don't have a heat sink / radiator with air flow to actually get rid of the heat rather than just moving it around.

Comment: So it's no use applying a heatsink in my case, right?

Comment: If it can get more surface area with airflow than the drive by itself, it's helpful.  If it blocks airflow to the drive without having a good radiator with its own good airflow, it's not helpful.

Comment: What would you have chosen in the scenario. Your laptop has vents near ssd slot(bottom right) but the fans' airflow direction is in opposite directions exclusively for the heat-pipes for CPU and GPU(top right and left). Options- a thin 1mm copper plate[Pi+™] , double sided aluminium thing[Advancing Gene] approx. 8mm thick. [ ]-Product brands

Comment: Ideally, you'd want something that can touch all the hot areas on the SSD to absorb their heat, and on the other side, fins with the maximum surface area that are parallel to the air flow to radiate that heat into the air flow.